# Gradle task to replace a attribute value with in a xml file

Tags: gradle, groovy

```
<a>
    <b>
       <c>ccc</c>
       <version> 1.0.0</version>
       <description> description </description>
    </b>
</a>
```

I want to replace the value of the version within the xml file with a different value in gradle task. Could you please help how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Following groovy code updates the value of the specified element with given value. You can use it to create task for the same.

```
def xmlString = """<a>    <b>        <c>ccc</c>        <version> 1.0.0</version>        <description> description </description>     </b> </a>"""
def element = 'version'
def newVersion = '2.0.0'
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
xml.'**'.find{it.name() == element}.replaceBody(newVersion)
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/36vxkU)</kbd>

**EDIT based on OP comments:**

Use `XmlParser and XmlNodePrinter`.

```
def xmlString = """<a>    <b>        <c>ccc</c>        <version> 1.0.0</version>        <description> description </description>     </b> </a>"""
def element = 'version'
def newVersion = '2.0.0'
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlString)
xml.'**'.find{it.name() == element}.replaceNode{"$element" newVersion}
new XmlNodePrinter().print(xml)
```

Comment: That seems to be working, but it also added the below header to the content
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration>"
Do we have anyother approach other than this.

Thank you

Comment: What other approach do you need ? can you elaborate what do you mean by that?

Comment: If I use the above script the output is 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>
  <b>
    <c>ccc</c>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <description> description </description>
  </b>
</a>

But I want the output to be 

<a>
  <b>
    <c>ccc</c>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <description> description </description>
  </b>
</a>

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
It worked in the editor (https://ideone.com/eRFNxZ), but the same code when I tested on my local machine, the version is totally getting disappeared. Not sure why, any idea?

Comment: @Sammy would you mind showing a screen shot for the same?